# using a lock in java

Tags: java, locking

Hi there
I'm building a little p2p program, so I want to make a file unable to be deleted while it is being downloaded. The simple solution is to use a lock, but then again I want it to be possible for multiple clients to download the file (meaning many thread can access the download method at the same time). 
I hope the situation is clear.
any ideas of how to implement it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). Use a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock fot the thread that is downloading the file and java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock for the other threads that should access it while it its being downloaded.

Comment: but i see that using this lock only one thread gains access to the lock, how can i make it accessible to many threads?

Comment: The trick is to pause the download in intervals, releasing the writelock for a short time. This enables all waiting readlocks to access the so far downloaded data in parallel. Then re-acquire the writelock and continue the download.. It is important that all read- and writelocks are acquired from the same ReadWriteLock instance.

Comment: ReadLocks do not block each other, they can access the locked area concurrently (if there is no WriteLock active)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of lock implementations at http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-frame.html which should help if all possible deleters are in the same VM, but there's no flock equivalent in the java core libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle the case when the deletion comes from a system call, that's unfortunately impossible in java

So either you cope with that and you guard your 'delete' method by a simple FileLockManager or whatever, or given the size of the file is small, you can copy it to another directory (1 temporary file per client/group of client for example) then the user can do whatever he wants with the original file

just my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

I have a programmatic solution for this problem

1. Keep a stack data structure for each file. Keep this synchronized.
2. Whenever a thread is invoked for downloading a file, it will push an element in the stack and when its finished it will pop the element.
3. Now the delete request for a particular file comes, it will always check the stack size and it succeeds only when the stack size is zero.

Problem with this approach : If a thread crashes due to some reason or the other, stack will always have an entry and that file will never get deleted.